# Gnome Settings: title bar buttons in the middle

Tags: gnome, titlebar, 20.10

I know that Gnome's title bars are not always intuitive and consistent, but how did I end up with this?

[image]

This is the Settings app which has the close, minimize and maximize button on the left of the "Info" title bar; however, there is a sidebar on the left with its own title bar, causing the buttons to be placed somewhere in the middle, in a very unintuitive place.

I like the buttons to be on the left and have used `gnome-tweak-tool` to move them to the left. In apps like Nautilus, in fact all other Gnome apps this works nicely, but in Settings, not so much. There is no way to resize the side bar.

This is Gnome 3.38.1 with the Yaru-dark theme, standard shell theme. Is this a bug, or is there anything I can do?

Comment: @Sasha I haven't found a solution yet. The `gnome-disk-utility` looks even worse: it has no close button and two hamburger menus.